# Retrieving Facebook Profile Picture

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bitmap

My graphrequest seems to work fine, I have no issue retrieving the User who logs ins Name nor do I have any problem getting their ID. I am trying to store their profile picture for use within my app (By downloading it as a bitmap) but cant seem to succesfully download it. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
   //Run the first time we log into Facebook
    //connects everything here
    private void firstTimeFBlogin() {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.i("joe", "Heyyyyo");

                        try {

                            String userName = response.getJSONObject().getString("name");
                            String userID = response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
                            //String hi2 = response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name");
                            //String hi3 = response.getJSONObject().getString("gender");


                            final JSONObject mPicture = object.getJSONObject("picture");
                            final JSONObject mPictureData = mPicture.getJSONObject("data");

                            final String mImageUrl = mPictureData.getString("url");

                            Log.i("joe", "User's Facebook Name: " + userName);
                            Log.i("joe", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                            Log.i("joe", mImageUrl);
                            Log.i("joe", userID);
                            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("name", userName);
                            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("iUrl", mImageUrl);
                            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("fbID", userID);

                            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();

                            profilePictureRetriever(userID);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.i("joe", "Couldn't Succesfully retrieve the stuff...");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();


    }


    public void profilePictureRetriever(String id) {
        Log.i("joe", "Profile Picture Checker");
        //Bitmap bitmap = getFacebookProfilePicture(id);

        //this is here for test purposes
//tried just maually putting the url in..
        Bitmap bm = DownloadImageBitmap("https://graph.facebook.com/849993771766163/picture?type=square");

    }

    public static Bitmap DownloadImageBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IMAGE", "Error getting bitmap", e);
        }
        return bm;
    }




}
```

Is there another/better way to be doing this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

I have done something like this:

First you need to call `GraphRequest API` for getting all the details of user in which `API` also gives `URL of current Profile Picture`.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "id,email,gender,cover,picture.type(large)");
new GraphRequest(token, "me", params, HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                        if (data.has("picture")) {
                            String profilePicUrl = data.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                            Bitmap profilePic = getFacebookProfilePicture(profilePicUrl);
                            // set profilePic bitmap to imageview
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
}).executeAsync();
```

You can use this method which returns current Profile picture of User from `URL` which we get from above `GraphRequest API`.

```
public static Bitmap getFacebookProfilePicture(String url){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    return bitmap;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hmm, in the line: Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream()); I cant seem to find the method 'openConnection();

Comment: DId you write that or is that in the library?

Comment: yeah cant seem to get that method to work, is there something i should have imported?

Comment: URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Pass required parameter in bundle, as `id,name,email,gender, birthday,picture` is passed in below code.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {

                                    }
                                });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,picture");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Cancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error");
                        Log.e(TAG, exception.toString());
                    }
                });
```

**Old Answer**

get it by calling

```
graph.facebook.com/<FB UserId>/picture?type=large
```

Comment: No longer available

Answer (score 0):

**following code is put after login success.**

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {
                                           Log.d("info",object.toString()+"");
                                           String id = object.getString("id");
                                            String profilePic ="http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture";
                                        }
                                    });
                                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,age_range,gender,locale,timezone,updated_time,verified,email");
                                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                                    request.executeAsync();
```